# Express triggers two routes with one request

Tags: node.js, express

I have route `/` and `/:itemId` - when sending request via postman both routes are triggered.

```
const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ok: true});
router.get('/:itemId', (req, res) => res.json({okk: true});
```

Not sure, what am I doing wrong.

Endpoint `/` is always returning a response, while second one is returning `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Express version: `^4.15.4`

Comment: Can you tell me after firing which request both of the routes get triggered?

Comment: Just `/` but it's now resolved, check answer below

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  There HAS to be more code involved because the code here will NOT cause `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` by itself.  These are two separate routes that each send a response and do NOT call `next()` to allow any other handler to run. So, your error is coming from some OTHER code, not from this code.

Comment: This question actually makes a lot of sense, it's about endpoints order, not the `Cannot set...` itself.  It's obvious, when two endpoints are triggered one of them will throw this error, question was about why is that happening.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzostak - No.  These two endpoints are NOT triggered in your code by one request.  The first request would HAVE to call `next()` before the second request could ever get called.  Plus, `app.get("/", ...)` is not hit at all when `/something` is the request.  That would be true for `app.use("/", ...)`, but not for `app.get("/", ...)`.  As I said above, NO code in this question would trigger the headers already sent error.  That error comes from something else you have not disclosed.

Comment: That is correct - I've found a piece of code which is actually triggering a `next()` always after request, did not thought about this piece of code. You were right

Comment: @KrzysztofSzostak - OK, I summarized my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

These two endpoints are NOT triggered in your code by one request. The first request would HAVE to call `next()` before the second request could ever get called.

Plus, `app.get("/", ...)` is not hit at all when `/something` is the request.

That would be true for `app.use("/", ...)`, but not for `app.get("/", ...)`.

As I said in my comments, NO code in this question would trigger the `headers already sent` error since only one of these two requests will ever get a chance to run.

That error comes from something else you have not disclosed and it has to either be a request that sends a response in two places within the same request handler or it comes from a request handler that both sends a response AND also calls `next()` to allow other request handlers to then run and send another response.